# 32bit OS, x64 based processor in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit

I wanted to install a software and they ask me to choose the 32bit version or the 64bit version. My PC is 32bit OS, x64 based processor, Windows 8.1 and I have no clue what I should choose. I will mostly appreciate a simple "choose this one". I know many people have great knowledge here, but a technical explanation will be wasted on me. Than you!

Comment: if your OS is 32bit, your applications MUST be 32bit (or smaller) as well.

Comment: Well, I have Windows 8.1, so I wasn't sure that other question would apply, and my processor says x64, so I didn't know if I had to choose 32 (OS) or 64 (processor). I already mentioned I know nothing about these things.

Comment: If you have the 64 bit processor then select 64 bit OS and install. That is the best thing to do

Comment: See? That is exactly my confusion. I have a 32bit OS and a x64 processor. In the answers, one says "if your OS is 32, install 32" and the other says "if your processor is 64, install 64". So, I still don't know which one I have to install. What matters, the OS or the processor?

Comment: Please explain why the comment provided by @FrankThomas is insufficient.

Comment: Simplified explanation: The processor architecture defines what OS you are capable of installing. A 64-bit processor allows 64bit OS and lower. The OS architecture defines what applications you can install. A 64-bit OS allows 64bit apps and lower. A 32bit OS allows 32bit apps and lower.

Comment: @Laura, sorry for the complications, I wanted to keep it simple. You want to match the OS, and ignore the CPU stuff unless you are selecting an OS to install.

Comment: Neither of the two linked questions is the same as this question.  The duplicate marking should be removed even though the information in the linked questions is of common interest.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the information by running "msinfo32" in command prompt or in "Run". This will give hardware and OS information. Like Frank said if the OS is running with 32-bit architecture, you have to install only 32-bit application.